# Non-static field 'listaCoches' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

estoy teniendo un error al añadir un objeto a un array en el método main, pongo un ejemplo para que se vea mejor.

clase coche,

```
public class Coche {
    public Coche(String color, int precio) {

    }
}
```

clase Fabrica con el método main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fabrica {
    ArrayList<Coche> listaCoches = new ArrayList<Coche>();
    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Coche cocheRojo = new Coche("Rojo", 9000);
        listaCoches.add(cocheRojo);
    }
}
```

Aquí tengo el error

> Non-static field 'listaCoches' cannot be referenced from a static context

cuando intento hacer el `.add()` para añadirlo al `ArrayList`, si quito el atributo static del main no me da el error, pero supongo que estaría mal y hay una forma de hacerlo bien.

Answer (score 0):

la operacion tienes que hacerla completa dentro del main , en tu caso tienes que crear el arrayList dentro del metodo principal.

Comment: Eso es totalmente incorrecto